# Sonar Cloud - Exclude Selenium from Sonar

Tags: selenium, sonarqube, sonarcloud

I am running a azure devops pipeline with sonar cloud and I wanted to exclude selenium folder from sonar cloud with following:
**sonar.exclusions=NWP.Selenium/****

And it did this [image]

It was not included in coverage but it was not fully excluded

Does anybody know a way how to fully exclude it ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out.
The command needed in azure devops pipeline is the following **sonar.test.exclusions=NWP.Selenium/****

Now I have this
[image]

For some reason Selenium is treated like sonar.test.exclusions